# Querying single field multiple times execution speed in mongodb using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Is there a difference in execution time between the two queries in `pymongo`:

```
db.collection.find({'date': {'$gte': datetime(2000, 01, 01), '$lt': datetime(2016, 11, 23)}})

db.collection.find({'date': {'$gte': datetime(2000, 01, 01)}, 'date': {'$lt': datetime(2016, 11, 23)}})
```

In the second case I am querying the same field two times. I checked using mongo shell and ran `.explain("executionStats")` and the only difference was in the queries (`"queryPlanner.parsedQuery"`) where for the first one it was:

```
"$and" : [
    {
        "date" : {
            "$lt" : ISODate("2016-11-23T00:00:00Z")
        }
    },
    {
        "date" : {
            "$gte" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00Z")
        }
    }
]
```

and this for the second one:

```
"date" : {
    "$lt" : ISODate("2016-11-23T00:00:00Z")
}
```

I am querying a collection with tens of thousands of documents and it is queried multiple times. So, I need to optimize the query.

Comment: Is the "date" field indexed? If not, that should be the first step for improving the speed of the operation. If it is, are there any differences between the two explain plans between how index bounds are applied? You may need to run .explain again passing the 'true' option, e.g. ".explain(true)"

Comment: Hey, I am querying multiple fields (approx. 6) on the collection and indexing the date won't help much. But the `date` field has a range and all other fields just matches for value equality. So, I think @hyades 's answer explains that my query is actually wrong and both queries are not equivalent because we cannot have same key for two different values in a mapping type (in this case a python dictionary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely at your second query -

```
{'date': {'$gte': datetime(2000, 01, 01)}, 'date': {'$lt': datetime(2016, 11, 23)}}
```

You should observe that this is an object(dict in python) having keys `date` and `date`, which of course makes no sense. You are trying to create an object with same keys. Thus, only one of them will be valid (the second one in this case). Thus the query to mongo is `{date': {'$lt': datetime(2016, 11, 23)}}` which wont give you the desired output.

I would suggest that you should define the query in terms of logical operators as clearly as possible. This would be the output of the `explain` stage in this case. Thus using `$and` to express two different conditions should be the best way to query.

```
{"$and" : [
    {"date" : {"$lt" : ISODate("2016-11-23T00:00:00Z")}},
    {"date" : {"$gte" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00Z")}}
]}
```

Coming to the topic of how to make the query faster, you should be using an index on `date`. Defining this index as a individual index `{date: 1}` would help narrow down to the relevant docs.